# How does Batman glide in the Arkham video game series?

Tags: dc, batman, arkham-series

How does Batman glide in the [Arkham video game series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham)?

I'm really curious about how that works.
Any answer goes.

Answer (score 2):

Christopher Nolan's Batman also has this ability.

If they use the same "technology" to achieve this then, as explained in *Batman Begins* the cape is made of a *Memory Cloth* which uses electrical charges within the material to make it rigid enough to glide and fly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this video, she just spreads her cape out and kinda uses it as a hang glider/parachute to glide around.

https://youtu.be/95ySRmdJRcc?t=28